# Classifying conjugate linear systems with 0 eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider all two dimensional linear systems with exactly one eigenvalue equal to 0. Which
of these systems are conjugate?

Say that we have the linear system $X'=AX$, since we know that one eigenvalue is equal to 0, this implies that the other eigenvalue is not zero and so we are in the case of distinct eigenvalues.

My approach is to use the fact that we know there exists an invertible linear transformation T, such that we can put A in canonical form:

$$T^{-1}AT = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Now I am unsure of the following. Are systems which are conjugate to systems $Y' = BY$ going to be conjugate to $X' = AX$?

Comment: Do "all linear systems" mean all two-dimensional linear systems?

Comment: yes, sorry I should have clarified

Comment: You are making the additional assumption that the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: I see. I am going off of the fact that we were told that for any linear system X' = AX we can 'change coordinates' so that the new system's coefficient matrix is in canonical form. Now I am also assuming that the non-zero eigenvalue is real and so the canonical form which corresponds to such a case is as I have written above. I am not sure how A being diagonalizable or not affects whether we can make this transformation?

Comment: Any matrix over an algebraically closed field can be put into a Jordan Normal Form but, for example, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ *is not* diagonalizable and the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ does not have any real eigenvalues. In other words, there is no $T$ for every matrix $A$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix

Answer (score 0):

Let $ A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ 
c & d
\end{pmatrix}  $ has exacltly one 0 eigenvlaue .
There exists an invertible matrix  $ T $ such that  $A = T \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} T^{-1}  $.
If we have two Linear systems whose matrices are $ A $ and  $ B $ with exactly one zero eigenvalue and         $ \lambda_{1} $  for $ A $  and  $ \lambda_{2} $ for $  B $.
we convert each system to his canonical form and find the flow map of each one:
for $ A $ we obtain   $ \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_{1} & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}   $  and  $ \varphi^{A}_{t}(x,y)=(xe^{\lambda_{1}t},y) $
for $ B $ we obtain  $ \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_{2} & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}   $ and  $ \varphi^{B}_{t}(x,y)=(xe^{\lambda_{2}t},y) $
the two systems are conjugated means that their canonical forms are also conjugated.
we search an homeomorphism $ H(x, y)=(h_{1}(x), h_{2}(y)) $ such that  $ H(\varphi^{A}_{t}(x,y))=\varphi^{B}_{t}(H(x,y)) $
 these means :$ h_{1}(xe^{\lambda_{1}}t)=h_{1}(x)e^{\lambda_{2}t} $ and $h_{2}(y)=h_{2}(y)$
we get $ h_{1}(x)=sign(x).\vert x \vert^{\dfrac{\lambda_{2}}{\lambda_{1}}} $ and( let $ h_{2}(y)=y $ )
clearly if one of $ \lambda_{i}<0 $ then $\dfrac{\lambda_{2}}{\lambda_{1}}<0  $ and $ \vert x \vert^{\dfrac{\lambda_{2}}{\lambda_{1}}}= \dfrac{1}{\vert x \vert^{-\dfrac{\lambda_{2}}{\lambda_{1}}}} $
not continuous at $ 0 $.
so the two systems are conjugated if $ \lambda_{1}.\lambda_{2}>0 $

Answer (score 0):

take $A=\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}  $ with eigenvalues $0$ and $4$ . And $B=\begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}  $  with eigenvalues $0$ and $-3$
$ \varphi_{t}^{A} (x,y)=(xe^{4t},y)$ and $ \varphi_{t}^{B} (x,y)=(xe^{-3t},y)$
the vector field associated with $A$ and $B$ is given in the pictures.
there is no conjugation between $ \varphi_{t}^{A}$ and  $ \varphi_{t}^{A}$ sine for $A$ the solution start from the straight line passes through the vector $(0;1)$ and tend away, in the case of $B$ all soluution tend to these straight line.
[vector field A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQJxB.jpg) [vector field B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvXCi.jpg)